# Strange '`'.dll file in bin folder, ASP.Net MVC

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-4

Recently when I build and publish my MVC4 project a strange file appear in my **bin** folder and I encounter the following error while browsing the website:

> Could not load file or assembly '`' or on of the its dependencies. An
>   attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

[image]

The website works well on the local IIS with the existence of these files.

When I delete these two files on either local or production server, it says:

> Could not load type "XXXX.MvcApplication"

What can cause this?

Comment: Have you changed anything in your code recently (you're using version control, right?) or your settings? Any unauthorized access to the machine?

Comment: I was added my project to TFS but now it's removed, i'm very interested to know why it's named by this strange character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your **project properties**(Right click on project and hit properties) and in **Application** tab change your **Assembly name** from "`" to the on you expected your dll name should be.

Comment: I guess it was renamed when I added it to TFS, thanks anyway.